# Why are image sizes used in CNN usually certain numbers?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am pretty new to computer vision and deep learning. I am always wondering why the dimensions of images fed in CNN models (or other models) usually in certain numbers like 28*28, 512*512, 256*256. Is there any reason for that? What will happen if I resize the images in arbitrary size? Will the performance get affected?

Comment: Are there any fully connected layers in the design or all the layers are convolutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most CNN architectures use images sizes that contain multiple factors of 2. That way you can downsample the images using MaxPooling multiple times without having to round the resolution to the closest integer.

```
512 -maxpool-> 256 -maxpool-> 128 -maxpool-> 64 -maxpool-> 32 ...
```

Sometimes you will come across resolutions where this doesn't work. U-Net for example uses resolutions of 572*572 where you could apply MaxPooling twice until you have to round the resolution. This is because U-Net uses unpadded convolutions where some of the image is cropped during the convolutional layers before MaxPooling is applied.

```
572 -conv-> 570 -conv-> 568 -maxpool-> 284 -conv-> 282 -conv-> 280 -maxpool-> 140 ...
```

I'm not aware of any papers that evaluated the impact of rounding resolutions during MaxPooling but my inutition is that it probably doesn't improve things. Personally, I used rounding a few times where the input resolution was given and didn't notice a difference in comparison to cropping parts of the images initially.

Comment: Thanks for sharing our experience. What do you mean by rounding resolutions during MaxPooling? Do you mean that you add a zero row and/or column so that the side lengths are even numbers before pooling? Do you have any reference to a paper where this has been done?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. No, I don't have a reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is the input node size which is defined during the design of the network. The training is also done using the images of that size. So, if you want a consistent result you should resize your input images to the same size and also follow the same normalization rules that were considered in the training.

If you use a different size image, depending on which layers are used in the network, you may raise a mismatching size exception or you will have a different output size.